# Why do some programs not write to a RAM disk on Windows?

Tags: windows, ramdisk, temporary-files

I've created a RAM disk under Windows using [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/). Most programs don't have problems writing to it. But for example, it isn't possible in Visual Studio (2013, currently) to create a project in a RAM disk, neither is it possible to download files to it using the popular downloader utility JDownloader. It says the drive is out of space, but there are around 7 gigabytes of free space on it. Why do some programs behave like that and is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you create a junction point e.g. in the system drive targeting some folder stored in the RAM disk?

Comment: Works on both Visual Studio and JDownloader. Thanks. But do you have an explanation why these programs behave this strange?

Comment: I don't use either of these myself, but providing some further information might help. For example, what's your operating system? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit? Which ImDisk version are you using? How did you create the RAM disk, exactly? That is, which settings did you pick? What happens when you try to create a project using Visual Studio 2013? Do you get any errors? What's the JDownloader version? Are there any other programs which exhibit the same issue?

Comment: What file system are you using on the RAM drive? If it is FAT32 then the "out of space" message may be from the fact that it does not support files larger than 4G. Assuming you were trying to download such a file, of course.